# .htaccess redirect subdomain before forcing HTTPS?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following rules on my website:

- Force HTTPS on all pages.
- Redirect http://user.domain.com to https://www.domain.com/file.php?user=user

The problem I'm having now is that when someone goes to http://user.domain.com , they get redirected to https://user.domain.com , which is then insecure, instead of to https://www.domain.com/file.php?user=user .

How do I fix this?

Here is the .htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.domain.com/file.php?user_id=%1 [L]
```

I also tried to change %{HTTP_HOST} to %{HTTPS_HOST} and it ended up with the same problem.

Comment: `they get redirected to` where?

Comment: Have you tried reordering the rules? Redirect to the page first, then to the https version of the page? I can't test it right now, so no guarantees! (You can also redirect to the page in .htaccess, then use PHP to reload as HTTPS)

Comment: Fixed my post to include where they get redirected to. And yes, I tried to put the HTTPS after the 2nd rule but that resulted in the same issue.

Comment: `http://user.domain.com to https://www.domain.com/file.php?user=user` will not be an internal rewrite since you're changing domain. Are DocumentRoot for `user.domain.com` and `www.domain.com` pointing to same directory?

Comment: user.domain.com is just an alias..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.domain.com/file.php?user_id=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /file.php?user_id=%1 [L,QSA]
```